# How can I test for the presence of an object in a List managed by Protocol Buffers?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have generated a Java API from some Protocol Buffers source code.  You can see it here: https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/  Things in the `hapi.*` package hierarchy are generated.  The semantics of this API don't matter for this question.

As part of working with this API, I need to assemble a [`Chart`](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/hapi/chart/ChartOuterClass.Chart.html).

With Protocol Buffers, when you are creating or mutating things, you work with "builders".  These builders have a `build()` method that returns the (immutable) object that they are responsible for building.  That's fine.  Consequently, in this generated API a [`Chart.Builder`](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/hapi/chart/ChartOuterClass.Chart.Builder.html) builds `Chart`s.

In this generated API, a `Chart.Builder` has "sub-" `Chart.Builder`s that it contains.  The list of such sub-builders is known as its *dependencies* and is represented via a smattering of generated methods.  I'll point out two interesting ones:

1. [`addDependencies` that takes a `Chart.Builder`](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/hapi/chart/ChartOuterClass.Chart.Builder.html#addDependencies-hapi.chart.ChartOuterClass.Chart.Builder-)
2. [`addDependenciesBuilder` that takes no arguments and returns the current `Chart.Builder`](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/hapi/chart/ChartOuterClass.Chart.Builder.html#addDependenciesBuilder--)

(I'll start by saying I have no idea what the second method is good for. It appears to stuff a new builder into an internal list and then...that's it.)

In the first method's case, if I hand it a `Chart.Builder`, this should add it.  Just what I needed!

OK, but now I don't want to add a `Chart.Builder` if it's already present.  **How can I reliably check for the presence of a sub-builder in a top-level builder?  More generally, in a Protocol Buffers Java API, how can I check for a builder inside a `List` of builders?**

(I understand I can roll my own "equality" checker, but I'm wary that perhaps I'm off in the wrong patch of weeds altogether: maybe this *isn't* how you construct an object graph using Protocol Buffers-generated code?)

You would *think* that I could call the [`getDependenciesBuilderList()`](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/apidocs/hapi/chart/ChartOuterClass.Chart.Builder.html#getDependenciesBuilderList--) method, and see if it `contains` my candidate builder.  But I've found this doesn't work: `java.util.List#contains(Object)` will return `false` for any builder passed in.

Surely this very simple treat-a-list-as-a-set pattern has a solution when working with Java APIs generated from `.proto` files?  If so, I'm failing to see it.  How can I do what I want?

(For further reading, I've gone through https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial which treats the subject in a fairly cursory fashion.)

Comment: Call `.build()` on the builder, and then do `contains` with the built object, not the builder.  There should be a method to get the list of built objects.  Adding a builder usually just calls build anyway. (Honestly, maybe you should be making a Set of Charts _first_ and then adding the deduplicated charts after you're done, instead of putting it all in the builder to start with.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  My motivation for sub-builders was: I'm assembling them from the contents of an `InputStream` and wanted to just do them as I encountered them.  Looks like in any event that won't work, as `addDependenciesBuilder(Chart.Builder)` immediately calls `build()` on the passed-in builder.  So I'll probably have to keep track of the builder hierarchy out-of-band and&mdash;as you say&mdash; put things together after the fact.